# I want to run Graphql Apollo query with as many ids as possible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

Using react ,apollo.
I want to execute useUserQuery for the number of ids stored in the state.
currently, it is only executed once because ids[0] is written in variables. Also, I can only get the data for ids[0].
I would like to execute useUserQuery as many times as there are ids in the state.

```
   const [ids, setIds] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

  const {data: {userData = null} = {}} = useUserQuery({
    variables: {id: ids[0]},
    skip: !ids,
  });
```

Comment: useUserQuery is a custom Apollo query, made in top of useQuery right?

Comment: Can't I run it multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by useUserQuery, let me assume it is a custom hook made using the original `useQuery`

A possible solution is to use `useLazyQuery` which is triggered manually, otherwise you can do it like this:

```
  let fetchId = useRef(0);
  
  const {data: {userData = null} = {}, refetch} = useUserQuery({
     variables: {id: ids[0]},
     skip: !ids,
     onComplete: () => {
         if (++fetchId.current < ids.length)
             refetch({id: fetchId.current})
     }
   });
```

In this case you can also use `useState` which will auto-refetch when changed.

Comment: Cannot find name 'refetch'. Did you mean 'fetch'?ts(

Comment: I get the above error at refetch()

Comment: you should add `refetch` to your destructed variables besides things like `data`

like this : `const {data: {userData = null} = {}, refetch} = .....`

Comment: I tried, but I can only get the ids[0] data.

Comment: fetchId.current is still 0

Comment: can you try replacing `refetch` with `refetch({id: fetchId.current})` ?